# jQuery: re-bind redactor after ajax save

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the Redactor text editor plugin for one of my projects. I am using a blur event, so that when I exit a textfield, it will save the text, like so:

```
$(".redactor_editor").blur(function(){...});
```

But after saving through ajax, and replacing the content with updated content:

```
   ... $('.content').replaceWith(data); ...
```

All the redactor textfields don't work.

How can I re-bind the redactor textfields after re-loading the content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the content is replaces try unbinding and binding the event again..

```
$('.content').replaceWith(data);
$(".redactor_editor").unbind().blur(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to re-bind the events, you can delegate the binding to the parent `.content` using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$('.content').on('blur', '.redactor_editor', function(){...});
```